# Accessing an instance throughout a tkinter app

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have a program that defines a Gear class and I am creating a tkinter GUI to manipulate it.  However I'm unsure how to make a globally accessible instance of the Gear.  Currently I am instantiating it like this and passing it into the sub frames I am creating like so ...

```
class MainApplication(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        
        self.gear = Gear.make_spur(50, 1, 20) # instance of gear creted
        
        self.home_frame = HomeFrame(root, gear) # Instance passed to home_frame
        self.home_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        self.calc_frame = CalcFrame(root, gear) # Instance passed to calc_frame
        self.calc_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")

        nav_frame = NavBar(root, controller=self, home_frame=self.home_frame, calc_frame=self.calc_frame)
        nav_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

This allows both Frames to work on the gear, but if I delete and create a new instance in the home_frame, the calculations I do on the gear in the calc_frame use the gear created in the above code.

Should I declare an instance as a global? or should I be considering a pattern like Singleton or Monostate?  It seems like this should be a common problem when creating a program based around a single instance of a Class, but I don't know how to approach it.

In Python there is supposed to be "one right way" to do things.  Which is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is best practice to create a single instance once and redefine the attributes for the lifetime of an application. This will lead to more efficient code with shorter computation and memory allocation.

However, if the need arise to create an entire new instance to REPLACE the previous one, the best approach is to use a single pointer that you access from everywhere else in the application. Gladly tkinter is built hierarchically and the instance of `tk.Tk` is the **root** of all other widgets. Shortly you can access the root window with `widget._root` in tkinter and every master is set as attribute as well, this makes it easy to maintain and access a single pointer. For instance:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Root(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main = MainFrame(self)
        self.one = FrameOne(self)


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,**kwargs)
        self.reference = object()


class FrameOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        print(self.master)
        print(self.master.main.reference)
```

With this built and due to the structure of tkinter itself you can just replace the single pointer with e.g `self.master.main.reference = object()`. The downside or rather the thing you need to be aware of is that if you do something like this:

```
class FrameOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.new_ref = master.main.reference
```

`self.new_ref` will hold the reference of the instance that is available at the time and does not function as some sort of link to a variable, that is how python works.
The attribute lookup in `python` is fairly fast, as far as I know, but you can still shorten the lookup chain by holding a reference to the object that hold the attribute of your interest as long as you don't plan to replace that one too.

Comment: Great thank you.  Is there a way print the location of the instance (ie find the name self.master.main.reference)?

Comment: @Inyoka Well every `tkinter` widget has a unique path from root `.` which is expressed like `.frame.widget` and is stored in `widget._w` or `widget.__str__` if that helps anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't understand how to access the my gear instance.  Perhaps because I'm doing it from another module.  However you have answered the initial question.  I perhaps just need to let the information sink in.

Comment: @Inyoka you can join the [tkinter chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249491/tkinter) if you feel like you want to talk about it.